# How get outpoint from txIn

Tags: transactions, transaction-input

I'm from Ukraine and do not know much English, sorry. I'm not understand where in transaction keep outpoint.

Please give me example or manual how get outpoint from input.

Comment: The developer pages of bitcoin might be a first step: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#term-raw-format, and then there is also the wonderful book from Andreas „Mastering Bitcoin“, which is also online available...

Answer (score 3):

Every transaction input consists of a number of fields:

- The txid of the transaction whose output is being spent.
- The index of the output being spent (also called vout).
- The `scriptSig`, or unlocking script.
- The sequence number.
- (SegWit inputs only) The `scriptWitness`.

The first two (txid, vout) are called the outpoint.

Comment: Thank you, but how get info of input input?

Comment: By looking it up. Find the transaction with that txid, and look at its output number vout.